# Problem with using JSON when trying get more data like "fields"

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have this code to get all information from website, I did it very well and it works, but I got stuck when trying to get "fields" from the site
This is the site url:

http://content.guardianapis.com/search?order-by=newest&show-references=author&show-tags=contributor&q=technology&show-fields=thumbnail&api-key=test

Here is the code and how can I fix it

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject jsonResults = jsonRes.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONArray resultsArray = jsonResults.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject oneResult = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String url = oneResult.getString("webUrl");
                String webTitle = oneResult.getString("webTitle");
                String section = oneResult.getString("sectionName");
                String date = oneResult.getString("webPublicationDate");
                date = formatDate(date);


                JSONArray fields = oneResult.getJSONArray("fields");
                JSONArray fieldsArray=oneResult.getJSONArray("fields");
                String imageThumbnail= null;
                if(fields.length()>0){
                    imageThumbnail=fields.getJSONObject(0).getString("thumbnail");
                }

                
                resultOfNewsData.add(new News(webTitle url, date, section, imageThumbnail));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FromLoader", "Err parsing response", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the fields object isn't an Array is a JSON object

```
"fields":{"thumbnail":"https://media.guim.co.uk/fa5ae6ca7c78fdfc4ac0fe4212562e6daf4dfb3d/0_265_4032_2419/500.jpg"}
```

An array object should contain [ JSON1, JSON2, JSON3 ]

In your case this

```
JSONArray fields = oneResult.getJSONArray("fields");
```

becomes this

```
JSONObject fields = oneResult.getJSONObject("fields");
```

And I don't understand why are you getting the same data twice - fields and fieldsArray